# hp deskjet ink advantage 1515 network printer

Tags: networking, printing, hp

i want to add network printer at ubuntu from Windows 7. already install newest hplib but when try to printing always failed.

is it because HP 1515 doesn't support for network printer or i done something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I own a hp 1515 and i found no way to make it a real 'network printer'. It doesn't have ethernet port, nor wifi capabilities.
If your printer is connected to a Windows machine make sure hp1515 is marked as shared printer over your network. Open Start menu, go to Devices and Printers, right-click on hp1515 icon, go to Sharing tab, check the 'Share this printer' box.
Then go to your Ubuntu machine, find Printer settings (depending on your desktop environment) and add 1515 as a network printer. You need the Windows machine to be running while any printing job, because printing is done through that machine. For easy management of hp printers under linux, make sure you install graphical interface for hplip, like this: Open a Terminal window and type: *sudo apt-get install hplip-gui* and press Enter.

Or you could try connect the printer directly into usb port of your router (if any usb available on your router) and check 'printer server' settings of your router (it depends on router firmware, usually done in an internet browser using a web interface for the router). If you manage to connect printer directly to your router, you will no longer need the Windows machine, the router will become the printer server and will manage all the print jobs.